# Conflicting jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mosaic

I would first like to say that this site has been incredibly useful for me as I have been learning web coding in my spare time. I have decided to register as I have a specific question I would like to ask.

I am working on my new website and a specific test page ([www.owenprescott.com/home.html](http://www.owenprescott.com/home.html)). I have come across a problem that I am hoping someone can help me with. I have a jQuery plugin that creates a hover effect over my thumbnail images and the inline code is causing an issue (jquery.dirinline.js), the function targets my (li) boxes and says this...
*$('.da-thumbs > li').hoverdir();*

The problem is that I have a couple of white boxes with project information wrapped in (li) tags. I do not want the white boxes to be effected by the above jQuery function. If you visit my site you will see what the issue is when you hover over the white boxes. I would be very greatfull on some input, either I need to alter the jQuery function or remove the (li) tags from the white info boxes however I am unsure how to get them to display correctly either way.

I hope I have not made this question to confusing and thanks in advance for any advice. Also as this will be my template page if you have any suggestions to improve my code feel free to let me know, I know I still need to remove the default Dreamweaver information.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question should be able to stand on it's own without requiring links to external sites. Please re-create your issue in a small test-case and include it in your question. Less text in your question may also yield better results due to more people actually reading it.

Comment: Kevin B is correct, however, your issue does not seem that far off base. I dont think you need to remove the li's (at work, blue coat wont let me see your site) however, it may require a different type of select statement. possibly even an issue of including specific class names. More information on how you are using these 2 libraries in your kode (aka, show us some work without us having to load the backend of your sight, for ppl like me, i cant see it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

So exclude them from the matched set. Use `not()` to remove them.

```
$('.da-thumbs > li').not(".someClassInfoThingy").hoverdir();
```

or check if it those info blocks will never have a link, you can do

```
$('.da-thumbs > li:has(a)').hoverdir();
```

Comment: Thanks I did not know about that, I think I have just found a work around since asking my question. I just added the position:relative and float:left which was applied to the (li) tags to a seperate class that is applied to the white box. :)

Comment: Or you can have the code not select them in the first place. lol

Comment: As a pro tip, i wouldnt rely on dreamweaver for learning coding, it will only hamper your growth...that being said, if it works in DW and not on the server, make sure your script libs are accessible by the server, might not be pointed at the correct location

Answer (score 0):

Your JS can be changed to:

```
$('.da-thumbs > li > a').parent().hoverdir();
```

And it should work with the HTML as is. The ones you want to exclude would match `li>div`, but not `li>a`, so getting the anchors and then selecting their parents will get only the items you need.